# Add new byte in array and shift the rest of the bytes

Tags: c#

I have an array look like this

> 17 8B 01 00 03 EA 05 00 14 0A 00 00 03 EA 05 00 14 0A 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF

I want to add an extra byte 0x00 after index 1 (8B) and move the rest of the bytes to right. The array is 32 byte long and after adding the extra byte (0x00) I want it to remain the same length as 32 bytes I dont care if I remove the FF at the end because its spare byte. So the new array should look like

> 17 8B 00 01 00 03 EA 05 00 14 0A 00 00 03 EA 05 00 14 0A 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF.

How can I do that in c#?

Comment: How about converting to `List<byte>`, inserting your `0x00` and then convert it back to an array (`.ToArray()`)? If performance doesn't matter _that_ much, this is probably one of the easier ways to do it.

Comment: Cant get why this got downvoted. Question is clear and provides the `have` and `want` of data.

Comment: Thanks guys.. I will have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
public static void InsertByte(byte[] array, int index, byte value)
{
    // shifting all bytes one spot. (from back to front)
    for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > index; i--)
        array[i] = array[i - 1];

    // assigning the new value
    array[index] = value;
}

public static byte[] InsertByteInCopy(byte[] array, int index, byte value)
{
    byte[] copy = array.ToArray();
    InsertByte(copy, index, value);
    return copy;
}
```

Altering the current instance of the array is better for performance.

---

Using Array.Copy will do something like this: **(untested)**

```
public static void InsertByte2(byte[] array, int index, byte value)
{
    Array.Copy(array, index, array, index + 1, a.Length - index - 1);
    array[index] = value;
}
```

Comment: True that its not specified, but maybe mutating the array is not an option.

Comment: Thats also not specified. But I'll add an extra option.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen You are devil bro work like a charm.. Thanks

Comment: You could always use [`Array.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than doing the data movement by hand.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I thought about that, but I'm not certain that copying in the same array will work. Does it?

Comment: But do you need an extra block _(memory)_ for moving? Because the source and destination are the same. Or does the `Array.Copy` creates an extra block.

Comment: No, it acts "as if" it uses an intermediate buffer. What this means in practice is that it works out the safe order to perform the copy (that you did by hand by working out to copy from the end towards the beginning rather than vice versa).

Comment: array.copy will replace the index two with the extra byte i want to add and I would have to add another function to sort that crap

Answer (score 5):

If you use `Array.Copy()` then behind the scenes it will use a very efficient processor instruction to move the data:

```
byte[] array = { 0x17, 0x8B, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0xEA, 0x05, 0x00, 0x14, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xEA, 0x05, 0x00, 0x14, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};

int positionToInsert = 2;
byte valueToInsert = 0;

Array.Copy(array, positionToInsert, array, positionToInsert+1, array.Length-positionToInsert-1);
array[positionToInsert] = valueToInsert;
```

`Array.Copy()` is implemented specifically to handle overlapping copies correctly.

Comment: for typing the whole `byte[] array` and offering the most efficient approach +1 :)

Comment: Nice one, was just updating my answer based on the comments.

Comment: Perfect answer, I put an answer copied from my utility class, but it's basically what this answer does... I'll leave it there just because it's an extension method, but +1 here

Answer (score 2):

Some fun with `yield return`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> InsertAndShift(this T[] array, T value, int index)
{
     //Omitting argument checks: null, range, etc.

     for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
     {
          if (i < index)
          {
              yield return array[i];
          }
          else if (i == index)
          {
              yield return input;
          }
          else
          {
              yield return array[i - 1];
          }
     }
}

var shiftedArray = array.InsertAndShift(0, 3).ToArray();
```

Its overkill I know, but fun nonetheless. It *does* have the advantage that it does not mutate the original array.

Comment: Won't this return an array that is original length + 1?

Comment: You're missing the `this` before `T[] array`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth True! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my utilities class:

```
public static T[] Insert<T>(this T[] array, T val, int position)
{
  Array.Copy(array, position, array, position+1, array.Length-(position+1));
  array[position] = val;        
  return array;
}
```

You can see a sample here (put as not an extension method): https://dotnetfiddle.net/vRcIuY

The usage as an extension method would be just:

```
array.Insert<byte>(0, 2);
```

No generic specifying necessary if the type can be inferred from the first parameter (not the case with a `0` and `byte` though)

Note that this mutates the array (returning the same array is just because I find it comfortable), you could implement it as `void` though

#### Update

I just noticed (that was the intended use in my utility class) that this would return an array of the same length as the original (thus clipping by one). If you want to return a new array with 1 more item (in your question you say you don't care, but just in case), you can just do this:

```
public static T[] ArrayInsert<T>(this T[] array, T val, int position)
{
  var ret = new T[array.Length+1];
  if(position != 0)
    Array.Copy(array, 0, ret, 0, position);
  ret[position] = val;
  Array.Copy(array, position, ret, position+1, array.Length-position);          
  return ret;
}
```

This does not mutate the original array, and returns an array of the original length + 1, with the byte inserted.

Sample here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DpHldh